# Formatting Objects with one property per line when represented as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have an object:

```
var computer={
    "Home":{},
    "Desktop":{},
    "Documents":{},
    "Downloads":{},
    "Library":{},
    "Movies":{},
    "Music":{},
    "Pictures":{},
    "Library":{},
    "Downloads":{},
    "Files":{},
    "Devices":{},
    "USB":{},
    "Hard_Drive":{}
}
```

I output it into HTML with.

```
var exp=JSON.stringify(computer);
$("#targetDiv").append('<p class="text">'+exp+'</p>');
```

but the output is this:

```
{"Home":{},"Desktop":{},"Documents":{},"Downloads":{},"Library":{},"Movies":{},"Music":{},"Pictures":{},"Files":{},"Devices":{},"USB":{},"Hard_Drive":{}}
```

Example:

```js
var computer={
    "Home":{},
    "Desktop":{},
    "Documents":{},
    "Downloads":{},
    "Library":{},
    "Movies":{},
    "Music":{},
    "Pictures":{},
    "Library":{},
    "Downloads":{},
    "Files":{},
    "Devices":{},
    "USB":{},
    "Hard_Drive":{}
};

var exp=JSON.stringify(computer);
$("#targetDiv").append('<p class="text">'+exp+'</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="targetDiv"></div>
```

How do I format it so it would look like this?

```
{
"Home":{},
"Desktop":{},
"Documents":{},
"Downloads":{},
"Library":{},
"Movies":{},
"Music":{},
"Pictures":{},
"Files":{},
"Devices":{},
"USB":{},
"Hard_Drive":{}
}
```

I think I need a loop that loops through the output and whenever there is a `,` or a `}`, it puts a `<br/>` HTML tag, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(computer, 0, 1)` inside `<pre>`.

Comment: @Tushar I don't have a <pre> tag though

Comment: It should work with `<p>` as well.

Comment: @Mritunjay where exactly do i put  
JSON.stringify(computer, 0, 1)?

Comment: Where `helps` defined?

Comment: You have defined no variable called `helps`. How do you get any output? You have a variable `computer`.

Comment: @Makyen oops fixed that. check again

Comment: @guest271314 oops fixed that. check again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tushar mentioned, one way is to put the output of [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) inside a [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre).

```js
$("#targetDiv").append('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(computer,null,1) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Set up the 'computer' variable:-->
<script>var computer={ "Home":{},"Desktop":{},"Documents":{},"Downloads":{},"Library":{},
    "Movies":{},"Music":{},"Pictures":{},"Library":{},"Downloads":{},"Files":{},
    "Devices":{},"USB":{},"Hard_Drive":{} }</script>
<div id="targetDiv"></div>
```

If you want to use a `<pre>`, but really don't want the whitespace at the beginning of each line (i.e. formatted exactly as in the desired output in the question):

```js
$("#targetDiv").append('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(computer,null,1).replace(/^\s*/gm,'') + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Set up the 'computer' variable:-->
<script>var computer={ "Home":{},"Desktop":{},"Documents":{},"Downloads":{},"Library":{},
    "Movies":{},"Music":{},"Pictures":{},"Library":{},"Downloads":{},"Files":{},
    "Devices":{},"USB":{},"Hard_Drive":{} }</script>
<div id="targetDiv"></div>
```

If you don't want to use a `<pre>`, you could separate the lines with a `<br/>`.

```js
$("#targetDiv").append(JSON.stringify(computer,null,'<br/>').replace(/}\s*}/,'}<br/>}'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Set up the 'computer' variable:-->
<script>var computer={ "Home":{},"Desktop":{},"Documents":{},"Downloads":{},"Library":{},
    "Movies":{},"Music":{},"Pictures":{},"Library":{},"Downloads":{},"Files":{},
    "Devices":{},"USB":{},"Hard_Drive":{} }</script>
<div id="targetDiv"></div>
```

Alternately, you could enclose each line in a `<p class="text"></p>`.  The code in your question implies that this is what you desire.

```js
//Note: The following uses replace to both enclose each line in <p></p> and remove
//  all excess whitespace.  Removing the whitespace is not needed, but may be
//  desirable as including the whitespace results in additional text nodes between
//  each <p>.
$("#targetDiv").append(JSON.stringify(computer,null,1).replace(/^\s*([^\n]*)\n/gm,'<p class="text">$1</p>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Set up the 'computer' variable:-->
<script>var computer={ "Home":{},"Desktop":{},"Documents":{},"Downloads":{},"Library":{},
    "Movies":{},"Music":{},"Pictures":{},"Library":{},"Downloads":{},"Files":{},
    "Devices":{},"USB":{},"Hard_Drive":{} }</script>
<div id="targetDiv"></div>
```

Comment: This is good, although it has more white-space than the OP asked for.

Comment: @nnnnnn, You have a point. I added three alternatives which provide for not displaying the whitespace at the beginning of each line (and/or having it exist).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.each()`, `JSON.stringify()`, `.append()`, `.html()`, `.lastIndexOf()`, `.slice()`

```
$().ready(function() {

  var computer = {
    "Home": {},
    "Desktop": {},
    "Documents": {},
    "Downloads": {},
    "Library": {},
    "Movies": {},
    "Music": {},
    "Pictures": {},
    "Files": {},
    "Devices": {},
    "USB": {},
    "Hard_Drive": {}
  }

  var div = $("#targetDiv");
  div.html("{<br>");

  $.each(computer, function(key, value) {
    div.append(`"${key}":${JSON.stringify(value)},<br>`)
  });

  div.html(function(_, html) {
    // remove last comma
    var lastcomma = html.lastIndexOf(",");
    html = html.slice(0, lastcomma) + html.slice(lastcomma + 1)
    return html + "}"
  });

});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bh9mheg1/1